# Confused with Quadratic Functions: A Number of Questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

In 10th grade, I learned that $ax^2 + bx + c$ is a **quadratic function**

I'm currently learning how to "investigate quadratic functions in vertex form" and in my textbook, they define $f(x) = x^2$ as the simplest form of a quadratic function. I don't understand how this is the simplest form of a quadratic function, was it derived from the first mentioned equation?

Comment: Never mind, I got the second problem... (I deleted it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=x^2$ is the simplest form because $a=1$ and $c=0$, it can't get any simpler than that. it's quadratic $x$ is raised to the second power.

Comment: what about the first degree term (b)?

Comment: ax^2+bx+c is a trinomial, if the trinomial is the product of two binomials, then bx is the result of the sum of the products of the first-last terms and last-first terms respectively. In the example f(x)=x^2 the coefficient a=1, and constant c=0, thus bx= 1*x . So in summary of the simplest form of a quadratic function a=1, b=1 and c=0 .

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand what your textbook means by stating "$f(x)=x^2$ is the simplest form of a quadratic function". The phrase *simplest form* is generally used when you have an expression but according to the concept, it is inappropriate to use that expression so you find it's *simplest form* in order to make things easier. If we give an example, say we are finding the roots of the equation $x^2+5x+6=0$, the simplest form of the polynomial on LHS is $(x+3)(x+2)$ because we are seeking the $x$ values that makes LHS$=0$ and it is easier to find them using the second expression. But for another concept, simplest form may be the expression $x^2+5x+6$.

I think what they mean by saying that is that $f(x)=x^2$ is a "simple" function to examplify the quadratic functions because as stated above, we have $a = 1$, $b=c=0$. But in my opinion, all of the quadratic functions with $b=c=0$, in other words $f(x) = ax^2$, can be thought as "simple" in real plane since these functions really look alike:

[image]